# Embed Javascript and PHO in Wordpress Page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to call a form and prepopulate it with an email address variable pulled using PHP.

Here's the code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.jotform.co/jsform/40125085918858?email=<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->user_email ?>"></script>
```

This isn't the form I'm using, but is an example. The code is the same.

The problem is that the email address isn't displayed. I suspect it's the way that Wordpress handles PHP in the pages themselves.

How can I correct this? I've tried different plugins that allow for PHP code snippets, but that's not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the code block to include the whole code which was not included in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function call outside of the HTML i.e.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
src="https://secure.jotform.co/jsform/40125085918858?email=echo $current_user->user_email ?>">>
```

I would also look at the generated code to see what is actually being generated.